# Renomeando arquivo: 'str' object has no attribute 'group'

Tags: python, python-3.x

estou com um problema que talvez possa ser bem trivial mas não estou conseguindo entender. Encontrei em um texto por expressão regular uma sequencia numérica do tipo XXXX/YYYY, depois disso preciso renomear o arquivo .txt com a sequencia encontrada. O problema que está dando é que ao tentar renomear o arquivo o python retorna um erro porque ele não consegue renomear um arquivo que tenha uma "/".

```
    import os
    import re
    import random
    import string


    # Endereco da pasta em que os documentos se encontram
    path_txt = (r'''C:\Users\mateus.ferreira\Desktop\TXT''')

name_files = os.listdir(path_txt)

for TXT in name_files:
    with open(path_txt + '\\' + TXT, "r") as content:
        search = re.search(r'(([0-9]{4})(/)(([1][9][0-9][0-9])|([2][0-9][0-9][0-9])))', content.read())
        search = str(search)
        search = search.replace("/","")
    if search is not None:
        os.rename(os.path.join(path_txt, TXT),
                  os.path.join("Processos3", search.group(0) + "_" + str(random.randint(100, 999)) + ".txt"))
```

Tentei usar a função replace mas ta dando algum erro que não estou entendendo o porque:

```
      File "C:/Users/mateus.ferreira/PycharmProjects/untitled/classificador_reclamante.py", line 50, in <module>
    os.path.join("Processos3", search.group(0) + "_" + str(random.randint(100, 999)) + ".txt"))
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'group'
```

quando eu faço um print depois de replace ele retorna:

```
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(7449, 7458), match='82121991'>
```

ou seja match='82121991', mostra que pra retirar a barra o replace funcionou

Comment: Por quê você converteu o `search` para *string* em `search = str(search)`? Isso não faz muito sentido. Se você precisa remover a barra, deve fazer isso depois que capturar o valor do grupo com `search.group`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você está convertendo o retorno da função `search` para *string* sem sentido algum.

```
for TXT in name_files:
    with open(path_txt + '\\' + TXT, "r") as content:
        search = re.search(r'(([0-9]{4})(/)(([1][9][0-9][0-9])|([2][0-9][0-9][0-9])))', content.read())
        search = str(search)
        search = search.replace("/","")
    if search is not None:
        os.rename(os.path.join(path_txt, TXT),
                  os.path.join("Processos3", search.group(0) + "_" + str(random.randint(100, 999)) + ".txt"))
```

Inclusive está trabalhando com o valor de `search` mesmo antes de verificar se é nulo ou não. Se a intenção é remover as barras do valor buscado pela expressão regular, primeiro você deve capturar o grupo e somente depois substituir, não o contrário, como você fez.

Seria algo como:

```
with open(path_txt + '\\' + TXT, "r") as content:
    search = re.search(r'(([0-9]{4})(/)(([1][9][0-9][0-9])|([2][0-9][0-9][0-9])))', content.read())
    if search is not None:  # Verifica se o valor foi encontrado
        name = search.group(0)  # Captura o valor do grupo
        name = name.replace('/', '')  # Substitui a barra
        os.rename(...)  # Renomeia utilizando o valor de `name`
```